# Why does render_template give a 404 not found?

Tags: python, flask

I use flask and trying to show my html file, however, i always get a 404. My html file is already inside my templates folder. This is the project structure below:

```
projectfolder/   
       app.py
       templates/
           frontend.html
```

this is the code:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('C:\Users\Software\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages')
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('frontend.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you put `app.run()` call too early,I suggest you move it to the end of your file.

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('C:\Users\Software\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages')
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('frontend.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In your code `app.run` is executed before any of your routes are registered.